# Given that $P(A)= 0.5, P(B)= 0.3$, and $P(B\mid A)= 0.2$, find $P(\bar A B)$.

Tags: probability

> Given that $P(A)= 0.5, P(B)= 0.3$, and $P(B\mid A)= 0.2$, find $P(\bar A B)$.

I know that the probability of event A not occurring is 0.5

I'm not sure how to find the probability. Would it be finding the probability of B given that A does not occur? Doesn't sound right though... or the probability of B AND A not occurring?

Comment: Yes, that is all the information that is given.

Comment: It seems that they are asking $P(B \cap \bar A)$. Remember Bayes' theorem.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

$$P(B\cap\overline{A})=P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(B)-P(A)P(B|A)=0.3-(0.5)(0.2)$$

Answer (score 0):

msm elegantly uses

$$P(B \setminus A) = P(B) - P(B \cap A)$$

I think that's excision.

---

Alternatively, you can use law of total probability and Bayes' Theorem:

1. Use LoTP to compute $P(B|A^C)$:

$$P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|A^C)P(A^C)$$

2. Use Bayes':

$$P(A^C \cap B) = P(A^C)P(B|A^C)$$